# Assign Data to JavaScript Variable from Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is there anyway to assign data to multiple javascript variables? I am trying to trigger something onblur which would change some other fields contained within the VF Form. They will go on their lookup field, then click the content then it will fill content in a SELECT.

I am wondering if you could send references/pointers of the variables to the controller, so it can assign the variables there and send it back. Or am i forced to have multiple functions with multiple returns to try and get it done.

I know about remoteActions but that will only give me back one return. Just looking to get it done in one function instead of multiple ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totally!  Whenever you use a formula in a Visualforce page, `{! ... }`, Apex calculates the formula, and writes the result right into the DOM.  So to set a variable in Javascript:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="getContactsExtension" ...>
    ....

    <script>
        var accountId='{!Account.id}';  // NOTE: I wrapped the value in quotes so Javascript interprets it as a string
        var ContactArray = {!ContactList};

        alert('The Account Id = '+accountId);

        // etc....
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, this is what i was hoping for. But it seems like it doesn't work. I assign the Variable in controller then in js i use your syntax. String comes back blank.

Comment: try console.log(yourVar) or alert(yourVar) and see that it works.  Try adding the alert statement as I did in my updated solution

Comment: I understand account working because you have the main controller available for it however, I have a variable defined in my controller that is `String Payment{get; set;}` I assign the variable using an actionFunction, then i try and get the string using `var x = {!Payment};` to no avail blank on the alerts.

Comment: well, if you use an Action Function, you are probably doing AJAX requests and changing the DOM.  Make sure you rerender your script!   (Wrap your <script> block with an <apex:outputPanel>  and rerender that Panel in your Action Function)

Answer (score 2):

Remote Action methods return variable can be of type list or custom wrapper class as well.So you can return as a list instead of one variable .

Comment: Great thanks i realized this after i could have just made a list and send what i need with it. Would you happen to know if ActionFunctions can return variables?

Comment: Please upvote and accept if that helps .Also Action Function cant but you can use getters and setters and use getter to return data to javascript too

Comment: @James can you accept Mohith answer and upvote if it helps you. He answered correctly and clearly.

Comment: isn't the question how to
"Assign Data to JavaScript Variable from Controller"?  just sayin @baskaran